# Making DB backups in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-backups

There is a `gem db2fog` but it works only with Rails 3.
Is there anyting suitable for making databases backups in Rails 4?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look to [Backup](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) gem. It provides a very nice set of features like:

- Databases support: MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, Redis ...
- Compression
- Encryption
- Storages: Amazon S3, Local, RSync, Dropbox ...
- Notifiers: Email, Twitter, Hipchat ...
- Friendly DSL

The plugin is totally independent to `Rails`, so you can use it for other applications.

Backup model example (MySQL, Amazon, Gzip and email notifications):

```
Model.new(:my_backup, 'My backup description') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    db.name     = "database_name"
    db.username = "username"
    db.password = "pass"
    db.host     = "localhost"
    db.port     = 3306
  end

  store_with S3 do |s3|
    s3.access_key_id     = "access_key_id"
    s3.secret_access_key = "secret_access_key"
    s3.bucket            = "bucket_name"
    s3.path              = "path/to/your/backups"
  end

  compress_with Gzip

  notify_by Mail do |mail|
    mail.on_success     = true
    mail.on_warning     = true
    mail.on_failure     = true

    mail.from           = "sender@email.com"
    mail.to             = "receiver@email.com"
    mail.address        = "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail.port           = 587
    mail.domain         = "your.host.name"
    mail.user_name      = "sender@email.com"
    mail.password       = "pass"
    mail.authentication = "plain"
  end
end
```

Perform the backup:

```
$ backup perform --trigger my_backup
```

Schedule your backups with a cron job (for example with `whenever` gem) and you'll achieve a simple and effective solution:

```
every 1.day, :at => '1:00 am' do
  command "backup perform --trigger my_backup"
end
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I use this as well; works great.  I install / setup with a capistrano recipe and use whenever to schedule the backup as a cron job.

Comment: It's exactly what I need.  
Thx a lot.

Comment: thanks it is really helpful./

Answer (score 0):

I know that your problem is already solved, but I wanted to add [Dumper.io](http://dumper.io) tool to this thread. I simple love the simplicity of this tool.